# Simple python image uploader using CGI

Tags: python, upload

I'm looking for a script that can allow someone to simply upload an image using CGI and will store the image in my /img/ folder. I tried using this one (http://webpython.codepoint.net/cgi_file_upload) but it gave this error:

```
<type 'exceptions.KeyError'>: 'file' 
args = ('file',) 
message = 'file'
```

Really anything simple will do. Just upload an image and save it.

Thanks!

Comment: What does your POST data look like in the browser, and what does `print(form)` say if you add that to line ~13?

Comment: The code seems to work here, with firefox and chrome. Could you provide some more details? What browser are you using? What OS? Which python version?

Comment: 17 # Test if the file was uploaded
fileitem undefined, form = FieldStorage(None, None, [])
 /usr/local/lib/python-2.6.4/lib/python2.6/cgi.py in __getitem__(self=FieldStorage(None, None, []), key='file')
  539             if item.name == key: found.append(item)
  540         if not found:
  541             raise KeyError, key
  542         if len(found) == 1:
  543             return found[0]
builtin KeyError = <type 'exceptions.KeyError'>, key = 'file'
<type 'exceptions.KeyError'>: 'file' 
      args = ('file',) 
      message = 'file'

Comment: That's the error I get. print(form) just causes a server error. I'm running Python 2. I'm on Safari OSX Maverick.

Comment: Alright I got it to work! Thanks for all your help. I had misread the part that /files had to be in that same directory